# Is a cold engine possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

A while ago, I watched a video on electric cars and they referred to "ice cars".  This sounded rather surprising but I eventually realized that it was "ICE" meaning "internal combustion engine. However, it made me speculate on the possibility of an engine powered by ice: a heat engine in reverse.  Obviously, it would be ridiculously impractical and inefficient but it would seem possible.  One problem, of many, is that would be useless if the ambient temperature dropped below $0$C.  On the plus side in the warmer countries, you might get air conditioning as a by-product as you can get heating from a more regular ICE car.

Is it possible?

Comment: Re, "...an engine powered by ice: a heat engine in reverse..." But that wouldn't be "in reverse." You'd still call it a _heat_ engine. A heat engine is not powered by heat. It is powered by the _flow_ of heat from a heat source to a heat sink. Toy Stirling engines, especially the ["pancake" style](https://www.amazon.com/T-Language-Miniature-Temperature-Stirling-PuzzleToys/dp/B075MLDC5C/)), can operate on the temperature difference between warm room air (the source) and a bed of crushed ice (the sink).

Comment: Indeed, "reverse" could give the wrong impression.  I just meant that the reservoir is warmer rather than cooler as usual.

Comment: Of course, there _is_ a way in which "reverse heat engine" makes sense: A [_heat pump_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump_and_refrigeration_cycle) (e.g., a refrigerator or an air conditioner) arguably is a heat engine operating in reverse. You put mechanical energy into it instead of taking mechanical energy from it, and it forces heat to flow "in reverse" from a cold reservoir to a hot reservoir.

Answer (score 3):

Possible, but ridiculously impractical as you mentioned. it takes way more energy to bring temperature down to desired level than make it hot.
You can easily make several hundred Celsius with a match, but it requires a room sized equipment to make -80 Celsius.
Plus, doesn't really have nothing to do with 0 Celsius tho since ice can have arbitrary temperature below 0 in 1 atm.

Comment: Good point on the $0$C but I thought that a phase transition would help.

Comment: Simply speaking, engines run by the volume difference of fluid (in most case air) which is proportional to temperature difference. phase transition is too minor factor for that.

Comment: So, my ice engine will be very bad.

Comment: I thought we already had a consensus to it. It is terribly bad, but possible tho.

Comment: When you have thermal reservoirs of different temperatures it is possible to extract work through a heat engine; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine

Comment: @Kiw We do.  I just meant that it might be even worse than I first thought.

Answer (score 2):

[Liquid nitrogen-powered cars have been around since 1902 (!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_nitrogen_engine). An ice-powered car would be possible if you could find a good working fluid that boils at ambient temperature and condenses at 0C.

A heat engine works by having a temperature difference between two reservoirs, and there is no need for one to be hot, just hotter - except of course efficiency.